# form_set_error: How to set for an array Drupal 6

Tags: ubercart

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nid] => 164
                    [module] => uc_product
                    [remove] => Remove
                    [title] => Strokes1
                    [data] => a:4:{s:10:"attributes";a:0:{}s:9:"shippable";s:1:"0";s:12:"restrict_qty";s:1:"0";s:6:"module";s:10:"uc_product";}
                    [qty] => 2
                    [description] => 
                    [cart_item_id] => 200
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [nid] => 165
                    [module] => uc_product
                    [remove] => Remove
                    [title] => Strokes2
                    [data] => a:4:{s:10:"attributes";a:0:{}s:9:"shippable";s:1:"0";s:12:"restrict_qty";s:1:"0";s:6:"module";s:10:"uc_product";}
                    [qty] => 1
                    [description] => 
                    [cart_item_id] => 203
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [nid] => 166
                    [module] => uc_product
                    [remove] => Remove
                    [title] => Strokes3
                    [data] => a:4:{s:10:"attributes";a:0:{}s:9:"shippable";s:1:"0";s:12:"restrict_qty";s:1:"0";s:6:"module";s:10:"uc_product";}
                    [qty] => 1
                    [description] => 
                    [cart_item_id] => 204
                )

        )

    [update] => Update cart
    [checkout] => Checkout
    [form_build_id] => form-5c5819d5418df14f08153f1ce15d6acc
    [form_token] => 2341b9068b8ffb7454d267b22e572d7d
    [form_id] => uc_cart_view_form
)
```

I'm using form_set_error to display the error messages if there is no product.

My Issue is:

For example, I am having 3 products in the checkout page.

When I clicks submit I need to validate that all the products are available.

Here, let us consider if the second product is not available I am showing the error message "Product Stroke 2 is not available".

**But all the check boxes in the cart is highlighted**

Because I had set form_set_error to items element.

**How can I set form_set_error for *every individual element*.**

What I have given to display error message:[image]

form_set_error('items', 'Not available');

Kindly guide me how to resolve the issue. I am using ubercart module with drupal 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a comment on the API page for [`form_set_error`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/6#comment-15099) which explains how to set a form error on a subelement of a form item.

From the comment:

```
form_set_error('field_name][i][value', t('Your message'));
```

Comment: I don't know why I was voted down, but the link answers the question. If not, please explain why.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but just posting links isn't a good answer.  From http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer, "A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there . Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: Well, I can understand this policy, but when api.d.o will go offline, all this site will be useless anyway. I'll try to complete my answer, though.

Comment: +1 for the updated answer according to SOF strategy.. And its working fine... Great : Cheers :)